# Read/Load image file from the StreamingAssets folder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a png image inside of my StreamingAssets folder. When I try to retrieve the image, it returns an image with a red question mark (this is not the right image). 
I am using this script:

```
public string url;
IEnumerator Start()
{
    url = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/shareImage.png";
    using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
    {
        yield return www;
        Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
    }
}
```

[image]

What should I do the get the right image?

Location of the image:

[image]

The Inspector tab of the image I want to change:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Application.streamingAssetsPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html)? The path varies from platform to platform.

Comment: @NathaliaSoragge thanks for the reply :) I tried `url = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "shareImage.png")`, but still the same issue.

Comment: 1.Show screenshot of where you put the file. 2.Where are you running this code? In the Editor or build?

Comment: Edited the post. I am running the code in the editor.

Comment: @Programmer any idea?

Comment: @Programmer yes it is. https://i.gyazo.com/98f16bf2515ba6cafc50a847ba10a0ed.png

Comment: @Programmer I can open the image and it's definetely PNG. Another image gives the same result. Unity version 2017.3.0f3. This is what the url looks like when the script is started `E:/Unity Projects/TurningTiles/Assets/StreamingAssets\shareImage.png`

Comment: Ok. Do `byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(url);` then `Debug.Log(imgData.Length);`. Tell me the log value in the Console tab.

Comment: @Programmer it returns `61976`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While reading files in the `StreamingAssets` folder, you have to use `WWW` on some platforms or `File.ReadAllBytes` some others. You check if the path contains `://` or `:///` then determine which one to use. This should solve the question mark issue. Note that you should now be using `UnityWebRequest` where `WWW` is required unless there is a bug with `UnityWebRequest`.

---

Another issue that will arise is the `SpriteRenderer` image not being upadte. The material will reflect the images changes but the `SpriteRenderer` will not. The proper way to change a sprite of a `SpriteRenderer` is to change the `SpriteRenderer.sprite` property. This means that you will have to Convert the `Texture2D` to `Sprite` then assign that sprite to the `SpriteRenderer.sprite` property.

Finally, use `Application.streamingAssetsPath` when accessing files in the `StreamingAssets` folder. This is not the issue now since you're running it in the Editor but will be in a build.

Below is what your code for reading image file in the StreamingAssets should look like:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public string url;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    ///url = Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/shareImage.png";
    url = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "shareImage.png");

    byte[] imgData;
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);

    //Check if we should use UnityWebRequest or File.ReadAllBytes
    if (url.Contains("://") || url.Contains(":///"))
    {
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();
        imgData = www.downloadHandler.data;
    }
    else
    {
        imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(url);
    }
    Debug.Log(imgData.Length);

    //Load raw Data into Texture2D 
    tex.LoadImage(imgData);

    //Convert Texture2D to Sprite
    Vector2 pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, tex.width, tex.height), pivot, 100.0f);

    //Apply Sprite to SpriteRenderer
    SpriteRenderer renderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    renderer.sprite = sprite;
}
```